# Subversion/Subclipse Install Problems

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I am trying to get subversion up and running on my Macbook Pro. When going through the install steps from other Stack Over flow posts and the Subclipse instal steps, I keep getting this error.

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /Users/Ryan/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

Does anyone have any experience with this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have JavaHL installed.  Typically that would mean using Homebrew or MacPorts install Subversion + JavaHL.

You can also install the SVNKit plugins from the Subclipse update site, and set your preferences under Team > SVN to use SVNKit, which is a pure Java implementation of the Subversion API.

JavaHL is generally preferable because it is part of the Subversion project itself.  But JavaHL is native code that has to be installed separately on your OS.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL